# Out-of-core computations in Julia

Tags: julia

I consider switching from R, Python and SAS to Julia and wondering whether Julia has convenient tools for out-of-core operations. I intend to use Julia on datasets of the size 10-20 Gb, so I would like to be able to manipulate them without loading them into RAM. Is there any package in Julia, allowing Julia to ‘just work’ with larger-than-RAM data the way SAS functions work?

Comment: Although not answering your question directly, I think my [disk.frame package](http://github.com/xiaodaigh/disk.frame) does what you want, but it's in R not Julia.

Answer (score 4):

[JuliaDB](http://juliadb.org/) is a dataframe package in Julia which allows for out-of-core computations, online (streaming) statistics, and parallelism.

Comment: JuliaDB does not work on Julia 0.7 or higher. Any alternatives?